# Finding all entries of an associated table in Sequelize Js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to find an array of entries from an associated table while querying from a main table.

Currently I am getting only one entry under the associated table when i try to query. 
For example, I am getting an output as follows.

```
{
    "id": 37,
    "name": "Mr Tom",
    "books": {
        "id": 1278,
        "name": "Book 1",
    }
}
```

As you can see the books part comes as an object in an array. I am expecting it to be an array of books.

**The following is the code I am using to query the data.**

```
const authorId = req.params.id;

const AuthorDetails = await AUTHOR.findOne({
  attributes: [
    'id',
    'name',
  ],
  where: {
    id: authorId,
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: BOOKS,
      attributes: ['id','name'],
    },
  ],
  raw: true,
  nest: true,
});
```

> The relationship between the author and books is one to many. Where a
>   book can have only one author but  an author can have many books.
>   This is defined as follows.

```
AUTHORS.hasMany(BOOKS);
BOOKS.belongsTo(AUTHORS);
```

edit: I noticed that when i remove the condition id:authorId it duplicates the author object and gives a unique book . For example

```
[
    {
        "id": 37,
        "name": "Mr Tom",
        "books": {
            "id": 1278,
            "name": "Book 1",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 37,
        "name": "Mr Tom",
        "books": {
            "id": 1279,
            "name": "Book 2",
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: How have you defined the one to many relationship in your models?

Comment: @v1shva , I have updated with the definition of the relationship of the tables.

Comment: Have you tried setting `raw: false`, and retrieving values as a sequelize object instead of raw result set? Does this include books array?

Comment: I tried setting raw to false now. It did enclose the the object in an array but it didnt show the other object. It should give me three objects but it still shows one. I know that there are 3 entries in the database because when i use _[sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('books.id')), 'bookNo'],_ inside the attributes of the main table i get 3

Comment: One possibility would be even there are three books they all not mapped to the author you are trying to retrieve. Check whether all three books have the same author id as the one you're trying to retrieve.

Comment: I doubled checked. They do have the same author id. And im sure about it because _[sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('books.id')), 'bookNo']_ placed inside the attributes of the author returns three

Comment: Check whether you have enabled soft delete on the books model definition(`paranoid: true`) if so deletedAt values of books is `NULL` not an empty string "";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195780/discussion-between-muljayan-and-v1shva).

Comment: No i dont have such a thing enabled.